# Is my proof that C = {x$\in$ N | x > 1} is smallest superset of the set of prime numbers that is closed under the function f(x,y) = xy correct?

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, prime-numbers

Disclaimer: I didn't formally studied math since high school years ago, so I apologize for breaking any conventions (I'd appreciate pointing that out if I did)

I have been self-studying math through Velleman's How to Prove It (3rd edition).

I reached this question: "Let f: N × N → N be defined by the formula f(x, y) = xy. Let P be the set of all prime numbers. What is the closure of P under f?"

This is my attempt to prove that  C = { x $\in$ N | x > 1} is smallest closed superset of P.

---

**Lemma1.** Every non-prime n $\in$ C can be written as the product of 2 or more primes.

Proof. Let n $\in$ C and suppose n is not a prime.  We'll use strong induction.

Since n isn't prime then there exists x,y $\in$ C such that xy = n and x < n and y < n.

We have the following cases:

Case 1. both x and y are primes. then n is a product of primes as required.

Case 2. x is prime and y is not. then by the inductive hypothesis, there exist prime numbers $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k$ such that $a_1. a_2. \ldots. a_k$ = y

So n = xy = x.$a_1. a_2. \ldots. a_k$

Case 3. y is a prime and x is not. similar to case 2.

Case 4. x is not and prime and y is not a prime.
By the inductive hypothesis, there exist prime numbers $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k$ such that $a_1. a_2. \ldots. a_k$ = y

and prime numbers $b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_j$  such that $b_1. b_2. \ldots. b_j$ = x

so n = xy = $\mathit b$1.$\mathit b$2.$\dots$.$\mathit b$j.$\mathit a$1.$\mathit a$2.$\dots$.$\mathit a$k

---

**Lemma2.** Let D be a superset of P.
Suppose D is closed under f.

For any n > 1 and any nonprime x, if x is a product of n primes, then x is in D.

Proof.
Base case: n = 2.
Let x be a product of 2 primes.
So x = $a_2 . a_2$ since $a_2 , a_2$ $\in$ P then $a_2 , a_2$ $\in$ D and since D is closed under f, then x =  $a_2 . a_2$ $\in$ D.

Induction step: n > 1.
Suppose for all nonprime y, if y is a product of n primes, then y is in D.
Let x be a product of n+1 primes. Let k = n + 1 (due to issues formatting with n+1)

So x = $a_1. a_2 \ldots.a_n.a_k$

Let z = $a_1. a_2 \ldots.a_n$

So z $\in$ D

since $a_k$ is a prime, then it's in D

so n = z.$a_k$ $\in$ D

---

Now proof that C is the smallest superset of P that is closed under f.
Let D be a superset of P.
Suppose D is closed under f.
Let y be arbitrary in C.

Case 1. y is a prime. then since P is a subset of D, y $\in$ D.

Case 2. y is not a prime.

Then by lemma1, y is product of 2 or more primes. and by lemma2, y is in D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, however can be simplified by combining your lemmas and thus avoiding explicit work with prime decomposition.

Let $D$ be superset of $P$ closed under $f$. Let's prove by strong induction that if $n > 1$ then $n \in D$.

Assume the statement is true for $n \leq k$. Let's prove that $k + 1 \in D$.

If $k + 1$ is prime, then $k + 1 \in D$ as again $k + 1 \in P$.

If $k + 1$ isn't prime then $k + 1 = ab$ where $1 < a, b < k + 1$. By induction hypothesis, $a \in D$ and $b \in D$. But as $D$ is closed under $f$, this implies that $ab \in D$.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Is the base case needed in your proof? It seems to me it would work even without it considering it's strong induction.

Comment: Actually, after you have asked I see that we don't need it.